# How to compile C++ with CUB library?

Tags: c++, compilation, cuda, cub

I am using the CUB device function just like the example here (https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cub-library/37675/2). I was able to compile the .cu source file in the above example using `nvcc`.

However, I wonder if it is possible to call `CUB` device function in .cpp source file and compile the .cpp source file (using `nvcc` or `g++`)? I know its possible for `thrust`, since the example [here](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/tree/master/examples/cpp_integration) works for me.

Currently I simply move the main function into a new main.cpp file and include the cub header file in main.cpp, but I failed to compile it using nvcc or g++ because of the same errors, part of the error message:

```
/home/xx/cub/cub/block/specializations/../../block/../util_type.cuh:261:5: error: ‘__host__’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__loff_t’?
         __host__ __device__ __forceinline__ NullType& operator =(const T&) { return *this; }
         ^~~~~~~~
         __loff_t
/home/xx/cub/cub/block/specializations/../../block/../util_type.cuh:316:19: error: ‘short4’ was not declared in this scope
     __CUB_ALIGN_BYTES(short4, 8)
                       ^
/home/xx/cub/cub/block/specializations/../../block/../util_type.cuh:314:52: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘__align__’ with no type [-fpermissive]
         { enum { ALIGN_BYTES = b }; typedef __align__(b) t Type; };
                                                        ^
/home/xx/cub/cub/block/specializations/../../block/../util_type.cuh:545:9: error: ‘__host__’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__loff_t’?
             __host__ __device__ __forceinline__ CubVector operator+(const CubVector &other) const {         \
             ^
/home/xx/cub/cub/block/specializations/../../block/../util_arch.cuh:64:38: error: ‘__host__’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘CUhostFn’?
         #define CUB_RUNTIME_FUNCTION __host__ __device__
                                      ^
/home/xx/cub/cub/device/../iterator/arg_index_input_iterator.cuh:144:25: error: ‘__forceinline__’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__thrust_forceinline__’?
     __host__ __device__ __forceinline__ ArgIndexInputIterator(
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                         __thrust_forceinline__
/home/xx/cub/cub/device/device_reduce.cuh:148:12: error: ‘cudaError_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘cudaError_enum’?
     static cudaError_t Reduce(
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
            cudaError_enum
```

Here are my source files:

**device.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <cub/cub.cuh>

void scan_on_device();
```

**device.cu**

```
#include "device.h"

void scan_on_device()
{
  // Declare, allocate, and initialize device pointers for input and output
  int num_items = 7;
  int *d_in;
  int h_in[]  = {8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9};
  int sz = sizeof(h_in)/sizeof(h_in[0]);
  int *d_out; // e.g., [ , , , , , , ]
  cudaMalloc(&d_in,  sz*sizeof(h_in[0]));
  cudaMalloc(&d_out, sz*sizeof(h_in[0]));
  cudaMemcpy(d_in, h_in, sz*sizeof(h_in[0]), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  printf("\nInput:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) printf("%d ", h_in[I]);
  // Determine temporary device storage requirements
  void *d_temp_storage = NULL;
  size_t temp_storage_bytes = 0;
  cub::DeviceScan::InclusiveSum(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, d_in, d_out, num_items);
  // Allocate temporary storage
  cudaMalloc(&d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes);
  // Run inclusive prefix sum
  cub::DeviceScan::InclusiveSum(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, d_in, d_out, num_items);
// d_out s<-- [8, 14, 21, 26, 29, 29, 38]
  cudaMemcpy(h_in, d_out, sz*sizeof(h_in[0]), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  printf("\nOutput:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) printf("%d ", h_in[i]);
  printf("\n");
}
```

**host.cpp**

```
#include "device.h"
#include <cub/cub.cuh>

int main(void)
{
    scan_on_device();

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile them in three steps:

```
nvcc -O2 -c device.cu -I/home/xx/cub
g++  -O2 -c host.cpp  -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -I/home/xx/cub
g++ -o tester device.o host.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart
```

The first step went well, but the second step gives the above errors. Any ideas are appreciated. Maybe I mess up some links (to cuda or cub)?

Comment: remove `#include <cub/cub.cuh>` from `device.h` and `host.cpp`.  Put it in `device.cu` only.  Then your code should compile.

Comment: Someone should add an answer to the question for future visitors.....

Answer (score 1):

The cub header library (e.g. `cub.cuh`) contains CUDA C++ code.  Such code cannot be compiled by an ordinary host compiler like g++.  You will get compile errors if you try to do so.

However your project doesn't require `cub.cuh` to be in your `device.h` header file, nor does it require `cub.cuh` to be compiled by g++.  The only thing needed in your `device.h` header file is the function prototype for `scan_on_device()`.

Therefore if you include the cub header file in the function implementation file `device.cu`, and remove it elsewhere in your project, your code will compile.